# How to update associated records from nested form values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having difficulties on a callback method I am trying to run. I have an Invoice that has nested forms for Purchase Entries (several invoice entries in one form). Each purchase entry has seperate product, quantity and price.

I have a callback function on the purchase entry to update the quantity of the associated product - such as:

```
class PurchaseEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :update_quantity

belongs_to :product

def update_quantity 
    if product.present?
        product.update_quantity
   end 
  end
```

Then, in my Product model, I have the following

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :purchase_entries

 def update_quantity
   update(quantity: purchase_entry.sum(:quantity))
  end
```

This however the update_quantity method updates the db with the total quantities in all purchase entries and not just the new purchase_entries created. How do I limit the method to only the entries that have been created?

Comment: You can use `before_commit :update_quantity, on: :create` or you can use `before_create :update_quantity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I limit the method to only the entries that have been created?

=> `before_save` is called every time an object is `saved`. So for new and existing objects. (create and update action)

=> `before_create` only before creation. So only for new objects (create action)

=> Rails 5 has `after_create_commit` `after_update_commit` and `after_destroy_commit` (`after_commit` is called after a record has been created, updated or destroyed.)

So, you can do this as: -

```
class PurchaseEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create_commit :update_quantity

  belongs_to :product

  def update_quantity 
    if product.present?
      product.update_quantity
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks so much - really appreciate the help. Needed to upgrade to Rails 5 at some point and now you've given me all the reason to!

Comment: @JeanMalan you can thank me by accepting/upvoting the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: @JeanMalan Kindly accept the answer for future SO searchers as well. thanks